# Function returning same variable separated by a comma

Tags: python, function, return-value, return-type, lsh

I don't understand the point of this function returning two variables, which are the same:

```
def construct_shingles(doc,k,h):
    #print 'antes -> ',doc,len(doc)
    doc = doc.lower()
    doc = ''.join(doc.split(' '))
    #print 'depois -> ',doc,len(doc)
    shingles = {}
    for i in xrange(len(doc)):
        substr = ''.join(doc[i:i+k])
        if len(substr) == k and substr not in shingles:
            shingles[substr] = 1

    if not h:
        return doc,shingles.keys()

    ret = tuple(shingles_hashed(shingles))

    return ret,ret
```

Seems redundant, but there must be a good reason for it, I just don't see why. Perhaps because there are two return statements? If 'h' is true, does it return both return statements? The calling functions look like:

```
def construct_set_shingles(docs,k,h=False):
    shingles = []
    for i in xrange(len(docs)):
        doc = docs[i]
        doc,sh = construct_shingles(doc,k,h)
        docs[i] = doc
        shingles.append(sh)
    return docs,shingles
```

and

```
def shingles_hashed(shingles):
    global len_buckets
    global hash_table
    shingles_hashed = []
    for substr in shingles:
        key = hash(substr)
        shingles_hashed.append(key)
        hash_table[key].append(substr)
    return shingles_hashed
```

The data set and function call look like:

```
k = 3 #number of shingles

d0 = "i know you"
d1 = "i think i met you"
d2 = "i did that"
d3 = "i did it"
d4 = "she says she knows you"
d5 = "know you personally"
d6 = "i think i know you"
d7 = "i know you personally"

docs = [d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7]
docsChange,shingles = construct_set_shingles(docs[:],k)
```

The github location: [lsh/LHS](https://github.com/andrecosta90/lsh/blob/master/LSH_impl.py)

Comment: Not all you find on github will make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct, and regarding why `return ret,ret`, the answer is that return statement is meant to return a pair of equalling values rather than one.

It is more of a style of coding rather than algorithm, because this can be done by other syntaxes. However this one is advantageous in some cases, e.g. if we write

```
def func(x, y, z):
    ...
    return ret

a = func(x, y, z)
b = func(x, y, z)
```

then `func` would be executed twice. But if:

```
def func(x, y, z):
    ...
    return ret, ret

a, b = func(x, y, z)
```

then `func` can be executed only once while being able to return to both `a` and `b`

Also in your particular case:

If `h` is `false` then the program until executes until the line `return doc,shingles.keys()`, and then the variables `doc` and `sh` in `construct_set_shingles` respectively take values of `doc` and `shingles.keys()`.

Otherwise, the first return statement is omitted, the second one is executed and then both `doc` and `sh` take equal values, particularly equalling to the value of `tuple(shingles_hashed(shingles))`

Comment: The extra return statement threw me off. I thought it was possibly a mistake, as the code actually does throw an 'out of index' error, when I set 'h' to true. But I see now that it is definitely unrelated.